# liammclennan/JavaScript-Koans topic array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have problem in this exercise:

```
test("stack methods", function() {
    var stack = [];
    stack.push("first");
    stack.push("second");

    equal("second" , stack.pop(), 'what will be the first value popped off the stack?');
    equal("first", stack.pop(), 'what will be the second value popped off the stack?');
});
```

in the chrome console works great, but qunit showing error in the second test.

Comment: About Arrays (topics/about_arrays.js): stack methods (1, 1, 2)Rerun3 ms
what will be the first value popped off the stack?
what will be the second value popped off the stack?
Expected:  
"second"
Result:  
"first"
Diff:  
"second" "first" 
Source:  
    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/Emil/Desktop/JavaScript-Koans-master/topics/about_arrays.js:31:26)

changing places "first" and "second" not working.

Comment: So your test case simply fails.